# Strip all characters in textbox except letters and spaces

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to strip all characters except letters and spaces but i am unable to do so. The code i currently have is below, how could i change that so it does allow spaces? At the moment it takes the text, strips it and it all becomes one big line of text.

```
    Dim InputTxt As String = InputText.Text
    Dim OutputTxt As System.Text.StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder()

    For Each Ch As Char In InputTxt
        If (Not Char.IsLetter(Ch)) Then
            OutputTxt.Append(Ch)

            Continue For
        End If

        Dim CheckIndex As Integer = Asc("a") - (Char.IsUpper(Ch) * -32)
        Dim Index As Integer = ((Asc(Ch) - CheckIndex) + 13) Mod 26
        OutputTxt.Append(Chr(Index + CheckIndex))

    Next
    OutputText.Text = (OutputTxt.ToString())
```

Comment: Look into the functionality of System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex. This will allow you to use a more declarative approach rather than a procedural one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim output = New StringBuilder()

For Each ch As Char In InputTxt
    If Char.IsLetter(ch) OrElse ch = " " Then
        output.Append(ch)
    End If
Next

OutputText.Text = output.ToString()
```

Comment: @MikeCole: and a much faster one, most likely.

Comment: And easier to maintain. :-)

Comment: Also, if you are interest in leaving all whitespace, not just spaces, you can change ch=" " to Char.IsWhiteSpace(ch)

Answer (score 1):

Not fully tested but a simple Regex should sustitute all of your code

```
   Dim s = "ADB,12.@,,,122abC"
   Dim result = Regex.Replace(s, "[^a-zA-Z ]+", "")
   Console.WriteLine(result)
```

*--> output = ADBabC*

Here you can find the [Regular Expression Pattern Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

And here is a way to use LINQ to query the string.

```
   Dim candidateText = "This is a test. Does it work with 123 and !"

    Dim q = From c In candidateText
            Where Char.IsLetter(c) OrElse c=" "
            Select c

    candidateText = String.Join("", q.ToArray)
```

**Edit**

Removed the Char.IsWhiteSpace in query to match the OP question.

Answer (score 0):

I think graumanoz solution is best and doesn't use any unnecessary operations like `ToList`, but just for kicks:

```
Shared Function Strip(ByVal input As String)
  Dim output = New StringBuilder()
  input.ToList().Where(Function(x) Char.IsLetter(x) OrElse x = " ").ToList().
    ForEach(Function(x) output.Append(x))
  Return output.ToString()
End Function
```